# CSS media query for Samsung Galaxy Note 2?

Tags: css

Trying to specify Samsung galaxy note 2 ..

so far I tried

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width:720px) and (max-device-height: 1280px) and(-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (device-aspect-ratio: 16 / 9)
```

And, many other ways with different form and values

Above code does not work as well...

Comment: have you added meta tag for viewport in header

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure those viewport sizes are right? 
Visit http://viewportsizes.com and search for your phone.

And maybe replacing `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:2` with `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2` would help?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to write both portrait and landscape media queries. Here's an example of a media query that targets the Samsung Galaxy Note 2 in portrait mode:

```css
/* Samsung Specific - Samsung Galaxy Note 2 Portrait*/ 
@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 640px) {
  #pageBodyBg {
   margin-top: 60px;
  }
}
```

You'll want to substitute the #pageBodyBg part of my example with what you're trying to accomplish.